# Tire gem: How to access Elasticsearch's 'highlight' property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I have some Rails models that are indexed in Elasticsearch (via Tire gem). I can index new documents and query the existing index.

What I can't seem to do is get ahold of the **highlight** attached to a record from within my Rails app. I *can* however see that `highlight` is returned in the json when I interact with Elasticsearch directly via `curl`.

When I try to access the `highlight` property of my record I get: `undefined method 'highlight' for #<Report:0x007fe8afa54700>`

```
# app/views/reports/index.html.haml
%h1 Listing reports
...
  - @reports.results.each do |report|
    %tr
      %td= report.title
      %td= raw report.highlight.attachment.first.to_s
```

But if I use `curl` I can see the `highlight` is returned to Tire...

```
$ curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/testapp_development_reports/report/_search?load=true&pretty=true" -d '{query":{"query_string":{"query":"contains","default_operator":"AND"}},"highlight":{"fields":{"attachment":{}}}}'
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.111475274,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "testapp_development_reports",
      "_type" : "report",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 0.111475274, "_source" : {"id":1,"title":"Sample Number One",...,"attachment":"JVBERi0xMJ1Ci... ...UlRU9GCg==\n"},
      "highlight" : {
        "attachment" : [ "\nThis <em>contains</em> one\n\nodd\n\n\n" ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "testapp_development_reports",
      "_type" : "report",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 0.111475274, "_source" : {"id":2,"title":"Number two",...,"attachment":"JVBERi0xLKM3OA... ...olJVPRgo=\n"},
      "highlight" : {
        "attachment" : [ "\nThis <em>contains</em> two\n\neven\n\n\n" ]
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

The search method in the model:

```
  ...
  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true) do
      query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
      highlight :attachment
    end
  end
  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `highlight` is inaccessible when you are using `load: true` option. This should be fixed in future versions of Tire.

edit: you can use `each_with_hit` method to access returned elasticsearch values now

For example:

```
results = Article.search 'One', :load => true
  results.each_with_hit do |result, hit|
  puts "#{result.title} (score: #{hit['_score']})"
end
```

Comment: Do you know when and how it will be fixed (accessing directly to `@response['hits']['hits']`)? Because I've not found in issues any info about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find my answer right at this post
[Elasticsearch/Lucene highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424927/elasticsearch-lucene-highlight/13395024#13395024)

My method works fine for me and wish you can get it work as well.